# asymptotic behaviour of polylogarithmic function

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, polylogarithm

I would like to understand the asymptotic behaviour as $a \rightarrow 0$ of the function

$$
f(a) := \sum\limits_{k=2}^{\infty} e^{ - a^2 k}{k^{-3/2}}
$$

More precisely, I would like to obtain an expansion in the form
$$
f(a) = f(0) - O(a^{\delta})
$$
and estimate the value of $\delta >0$.

The problem is that if I use the Taylor expansion and I compute the first derivative of $f(a)$ for $a=0$ then I obtain a divergent sum in $k$, so I think I cannot use this standard approach... do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

$$f(a) = \sum\limits_{k=2}^{\infty} e^{ - a^2 k}{k^{-3/2}}=\text{Li}_{\frac{3}{2}}\left(e^{-a^2}\right)-e^{-a^2}$$

Expanded as a series
$$f(a)=\left(\zeta \left(\frac{3}{2}\right)-1\right)-2 \sqrt{\pi } a+
   \left(1-\zeta \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)\right)a^2+O\left(a^4\right)$$ which a good approximation for $0\leq a \leq \frac 12$.

Comment: Thanks, where can I find a reference for this expansion?

Comment: @QuantumLogarithm   https://functions.wolfram.com/ZetaFunctionsandPolylogarithms/PolyLog/06/ShowAll.html

Comment: Thanks, in your expansion you have $\zeta(1/2)$ but this is infinite right, does the expansion still hold up to first order?

Comment: @QuantumLogarithm   $\zeta(1/2)=-1.46035$

Comment: Don't we have  $\zeta(\nu) = \sum_{k \geq 1} \frac{1}{k^{\nu}}$ and so $\zeta(1/2) = \infty$? Or is this valid only if $\nu$ is an integer?

Comment: @QuantumLogarithm That definition of zeta is valid only for $\Re \nu >1$. Beyond that it is defined by analytic continuation. A simple formula that is valid for $\Re \nu >0$ is https://dlmf.nist.gov/25.2.E3

Comment: but if I use the second line for the expansion around $z=1$ ($\nu > 1$ and $\nu \not\in \mathbb{Z}$) in 

https://functions.wolfram.com/ZetaFunctionsandPolylogarithms/PolyLog/06/ShowAll.html

I get that the second term in the expansion is of order $z-1$ which means $O(a^2)$ and not $O(a)$, right?

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici I don't understand where the term $- 2 \sqrt{\pi} a$ comes from...

Comment: @QuantumLogaritm Just use https://dlmf.nist.gov/25.12.E12